# 'eth_call' returning value '0x'

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, json-rpc

I am trying to call a contract function through the 'eth_call' method of rpc. my contract is as follows:

```
contract Ballot {

   function Ballot(string _title) {

       title = _title;
   }
...

   function getTitle() constant returns (string) { return title; }

...

}
```

I am calculating the method id for 'getTitle()' which yeilds '0x4e7ea493' which should return the title variable when sent in the 'data' param for the rpc call.

However it only every returns '0x' in the result, what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `geth`:

```
> web3.sha3('getTitle()').substring(0,10)
"0xff3c1a8f"
```

Your method call signature should be `0xff3c1a8f`.

Confirming using Browser Solidity and the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Ballot {
    string public title;

    function Ballot(string _title) {
        title = _title;
    }

   function getTitle() constant returns (string) { 
       return title; 
   }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of Browser Solidity's generated signature:

[image]

Comment: Apologies, there was an error in my code for calculating the method id. :P